# Sprite Image Resize - Make Responsive when resizing browser

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-sprites

I am having issues making the sprite  I have resize, when I resize browser window.
The remiander of the template is repnsive including the Nav Menu.

The sprite  remains fixed and sticks out of the page when resizing.

How would I make it size like the rest of the template (removing the width scroll bars)

If you just remove the sprite  everything displays correctly.

I have created a Fiddle but its not showing the  when I click results.

I have uploaded the page to here:

[Test Page](http://www.urban-marketing.co.uk/test/test.html)

Thank you.

Comment: Fiddle here if any help: http://jsfiddle.net/CZ97B/

Answer (score 2):

Perfect Solution I have Got U can Use
I have used This solution
And It works Fine on all browser except Android Browser

.playerSp
            {
                display: block;
                background: url(blue_sprite.png) no-repeat;
            }
        .next-button
            {
                background-position: -83px -6px;
                width: 41px;
                height: 46px;
            }

```
var abc=(screen.availHeight+screen.availWidth);
    $( window ).resize(function() {
    var aaa=($(document).height()+$(document).width());
    scale=abc/aaa;

      $('#playerContainer').css({ 'zoom': (1/scale), '-moz-transform': 'scale('+(1/scale)+')', '-moz-transform-origin': '0 0 ' });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

So I was stuck with the same question and noticed the answer was not yet given here. 
Here is the answer:

I've managed to make my sprite fully responsive. For this I didn't use any slicing (photoshop) or javascript. Also notice how the sprites are positioned absolute and yet still responsive according the background.

For a better understanding of this process, please see the following link: http://brianjohnsondesign.com/unlisted/demos/responsivesprite/

Also see my link in order to see how it looks on my website: http://demo.chilipress.com/epic3/
Should my link not work anymore, try the first link above.

See here the CSS and HTML

```
#sprite1_contact{
background-image: url('sprite_contact.png');
width: 35.2%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 7%;
background-position: 0 0;
background-size: 100%;
display: block;
top: 0;
position: absolute;
margin: 0 0 0 32.3%;
z-index: 2;}

#sprite2_contact {
background-image: url('sprite_contact.png');
width: 27.5%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 28%;
background-position: 0 27%;
background-size: 100%;
display: block;
top: 0;
position: absolute;
margin: 0 0 0 35.8%;
z-index: 1;}
```

HTML

```
<div id="sprite1_contact"></div>
<div id="sprite2_contact"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your sprites have fixed `height: 632px;` & `width: 1163px;` if you want them to resize youshould add at least a `min-width` and a `min-heigth` properties

example, if you want your sprites resize to a minimum of 10 px lets say you would add those properties to your code

```
#sprite-main-v2 {
height: 632px;
width: 1163px;
min-height:10px; /*added this line*/
min-width:10px; /*and this line*/
background-image: url(../images/landing-page/landing-sprite-5.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0px -700px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

you can also use media queries to change the image acording to screen width or height: example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {

    #sprite-main-v2 {
        height: 100 px; /*new size*/
        width:  100 px; /*new size, value just as example*/
        background-image: url(../images/landing-page/landing-sprite-5-small.png);/*smaller image*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate your help. But cant figure solution with either.
Solution 1: Had no impact
Solution 2: Stayed the same until browser was mobile size, then image disappeared but width scrollbars remained like the image was still there.

Answer (score 0):

Shrink your sprite to a smaller set size by adjusting its background-position and background-size css properties in a media query.

```
background-position: 0 -135px;
background-size: 170px 190px;
```

Those number are an example, you have to play with them to get it to line up with your sprite, which can be confusing as the image can disappear. Recommend adjusting them bit by bit in developer tools.

You can also use percentages to allow for a more responsive resizing, although this can get tricky too.

Note, background-size doesn't work on IE8 but neither do media queries....